# magento 2.4.3 detail product page on ADMIN really really slow to load

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, magento2.4.3

On my magento  admin, the product page is really really slow (it take around 2 min for loading the detail of a product) .

Apparently the javascript slow everything .

I have a big volume of attribute set, and categories (11000 each)
I suppose it s because of the volume of this 2 fields.

Do you know how to increase the speed of the detail page without removing attribute set , categories?

Maybe by removing this 2 fields on the form? Is it possible and how?

Comment: Attribute set structure would be a big drain. It might be possible to disable the "attribute set change" option on product edit, as it didnt exist that long ago. Instincts would say if it is possible it's better to have less attribute sets and leave some attributes empty on each product.